# How to store score in Android gaming

Tags: android

I have a small gaming application. For drawing the image and score I used one Java class which `extends` with `View` class:

```
 public class GameLayer extends View
 {
    // all of my code...working fine
 }
```

Now I want to save the score in Database but I'm unable to send the score into the Database.Anybody tel me how to send the value of score form simple java class which `extends` `View` to an `Activity` class where I called mydataBase.

I tried to use `putextra()`, `getExtra()` method but:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(GameLayer.this,B.class);----this part is not working.
```

Comment: can you post what errors you're getting exactly?

Comment: Did you tried with SharedPreferences?

Comment: if i use Intent intent = new Intent(GameLayer.this,B.class);

Comment: if i use Intent intent = new Intent(GameLayer.this,B.class); its giving an error msg like that....The constructor Intent(GameFirstLayer, Class<InsertScore>) is undefined

Comment: sorry for confusing....if i use Intent intent = new Intent(GameLayer.this,B.class); its giving an error msg like that....The constructor Intent(GameLayer, Class<B>) is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Use SQLite data base to store your game scores, by using function like this we can store information in that

```
private void addrow(String a,int b, String c)  {

     DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
     db.open();
     db.insertContact(a,b,c);  // this will be vary depends on your requirement.
                                       // string or int values..     
     db.close();
}
```

Comment: ya ya i already used Sqlite DataBase only for storing the score.but my problem is that i am unable to send the updated score form my custom java class(where i implemented onTouchEvent(), onDraw() all this method)that class is extend with View....i want to send the updated score from my custom javaClass to an Activity class where i did the stuff as u said above.

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(context, B.class); use context here